# Alert on missing series/data

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I'm trying to understand how can I get Grafana alert me when the metric is not being scraped anymore.

The metric I'm using for this example is `mongodb_instance_uptime_seconds`. When the instance goes down, the metric is not generated anymore resulting in the metric missing in Prometheus. At the moment the alert triggers on `when last() query(A, 1m, now) < 600`. As you can see the goal was to alert when the uptime is below 5minutes. Meaning I want to alert restarts and stops but Grafana won't alert when one instance goes down because the `last()` value does not exist in fact and when the instance is down for more than 5min it's not even reported anymore.

Any clues on how to move forward?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The metric that is typically used to determine if an instance is being scraped successfully is `up`. It is autogenerated by all scrape jobs, so if you want an alert for any scrape endpoint that is down, just use the query `up == 0`, which will show any endpoints whose last scrape was not successful. If you want to alert only for this specific endpoint, use labels like as `up{instance="mongodb.foo.com",job="mongo"} == 0`

If you're ever interested in using Alertmanager instead of Grafana for this, the rule would look like:

```
groups:
- name: General
  rules:
  - alert: Endpoint_Down
    expr: up == 0
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      summary: "Exporter is down: {{ $labels.instance }}"
      description: "The endpoint {{ $labels.instance }} is not able to be scraped by Prometheus."
```

Comment: on the alert configuration UI, where can I find `up`? I can see things like `avg`, `count`, `sum`, etc, but not `up`.

Comment: instead of setting alert on `up` alone, consider setting it on `absent`. for example: `absent(up{pod=~"deployment-name.+"})==1`

Comment: @samadmontazeri can you explain why? For me absent does not return any datapoints.

Comment: absent shouldn't replace up. absent's purpose is to check whether a timeseries is missing data https://www.robustperception.io/absent-alerting-for-jobs. In the situation above, up ==0 will return when nothing can be scraped, but if it just disappeared from discovery, absent(up) will alert. Neither is a catch-all @judos

Answer (score 6):

If you know in advance all the labels for the monitored time series, then [absent_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#absent_over_time) function may be used for alerting. For example, the following query returns non-empty result (e.g. an alert) when the metric `mongodb_instance_uptime_seconds{instance="foo",job="bar"}` had no new samples during the last 5 minutes:

```
absent_over_time(mongodb_instance_uptime_seconds{instance="foo",job="bar"}[5m])
```

Unfortunately both [absent](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#absent) and [absent_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#absent_over_time) functions cannot return multiple results if some of the matching time series disappear. For example, if there are two time series:

```
mongodb_instance_uptime_seconds{instance="foo"}
mongodb_instance_uptime_seconds{instance="bar"}
```

And only one of these time series stop receiving new samples (suppose, `mongodb_instance_uptime_seconds{instance="foo"}` has no new samples anymore, while `mongodb_instance_uptime_seconds{instance="bar"}` continues receiving new samples), then the following queries won't return the expected alert for `mongodb_instance_uptime_seconds{instance="foo"}`:

```
absent(mongodb_instance_uptime_seconds)
```

```
absent_over_time(mongodb_instance_uptime_seconds[5m])
```

Prometheus doesn't provide the solution to this issue yet, while [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) provides [lag()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#lag) function, which can be used for alerting in this case. For example, the following MetricsQL query alerts (e.g. returns non-empty result) when at least a single time series with `mongodb_instance_uptime_seconds` name stops receiving new samples for more than 5 minutes during the last hour:

```
lag(mongodb_instance_uptime_seconds[1h]) > 5m
```

This alert remains active for one hour after the time series stops receiving new samples. The duration for active alert can be adjusted by changing the value in square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @valyala using the metricsQL function "lag" works for victoria-metrics, but does not give an answer for promQL.

This promQL query will do a similar job to the lag function in metricsQL:

```
(sum_over_time(max by (env)(up{container="prometheus"})[120m:1m])<bool 115)>0 UNLESS max by (env)(up{container="prometheus"})
```

is equivalent to:

```
lag(max by (env)(up{container="prometheus"})[120m])>5m
```

Adjust the 120m and the 115 to adjust how long after prometheus goes down the alert will raise for and for how many minutes it has to be down before the alert is raised.

The above is a detection for prometheus itself going down on a k8s cluster. It will generate a non-empty response for up to 2h after the prometheus "up" metric disappears, which can be used for an alert. But you can do a similar detection for any scrape job by changing what is inside the sum_over_time() function.